# two css rules "seemingly" have same specificity weight but doesn't produce the same result

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

Ok, I'm trying to understand the CSS cascade and specificity as a 
"science" and not always leaving it up to "hit or miss" approach. I hope someone will help me out.

I have a rule:

```
.bluebutton {margin: 0 10px 6px 0;} /* rule 1 */
```

That I need to overwrite to change the margins in a particular instance.

So I added a `class` to the `div` and wrote:

```
.aside-right .bluebutton a {margin:30px 0 0 100px;} /* rule 2 */
```

However, rule 2 did not overwrite rule 1.

So I modified rule 2 to this:

```
.aside-right a.bluebutton {margin:30px 0 0 100px;} /* rule 3 */
```

and it overwrites the "`.bluebutton`" rule. /* rule 1 */

At first I wrote this HTML

```
 <a class="blueButton aside-right" href="enrollNow.html"><span>Enroll Now</span></a> <!-- html-1 -->
```

Then I modified and contained the button within a `div` and wrote:

```
<div class="aside-right"><a class="blueButton" href="enrollNow.html"><span>Enroll Now</span></a></div> <!-- html-2 -->
```

html-2 worked with rule 3.

Can someone help me understand why rule 3 overwrites rule 1 yet, rule 2 does not overwrite rule 1?  It looks like rules 2 and 3 have the same weight (to me).  Is it because rule 2 targets any `anchor` tag within any element with a `class` of `.bluebutton` and `.aside`, yet rule 3 targets only `anchor` tags with a `class` of `.bluebutton`?  I hope I explained what I'm trying to understand clearly.

Thanks!

Comment: That's because your original `rule 2` was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rule 1**
`.bluebutton` will target any element with the class `bluebutton`.

**Rule 2**
 
`.aside-right .bluebutton a` will target an anchor element nested inside an element with `class="bluebutton"`, nested inside an element with `class="aside-right"`. Example structure:

```
<div class="aside-right">
    <div class="bluebutton">
        <a href="#">link</a>
    <div>
<div>
```

**Rule 3**
 
`.aside-right a.bluebutton` will target any anchor with `class="bluebutton"` nested within an element with `class="aside-right"`. Example structure:

```
<div class="aside-right">
    <a class="bluebutton" href="#">link</a>
<div>
```

Comment: +1 @Jeemusu. Thanks for showing this structure!  It is clearer when I see it this way.

Comment: or anyone can help me out.  So I suppose you don't always use just the specificity calculation weight (0 0 0 0 inline, id, class, element) to overwrite, you also have to use the targets in the right places as well, right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your asking, but there are many many many ways of accomplishing the same result. Selectors can be overridden on multiple levels, right down to the body. I.E. `body div div.aside-right div.bluebutton a.link {}` . At the end of the day it all depends on the structure of your application, how your classes are reused, etc. Your obviously very new to CSS, I wouldn't worry too much, these things take time to get to grips with. Best thing to do is what you are now, just dive in, and ask away when you have problems. Plenty of good resources online to help you out too.

Answer (score 5):

Rule 2 does not select the same elements as rule one.

Rule 1 selects any element with `bluebutton` class

Rule 2 selects `<a>` elements that are descendants of element with `bluebutton` class which are descendants of element with `aside-right` class, from the html elements with the `bluebutton` class has no `<a>` descendants

Comment: `el el` (space) is a descendent selector.

Comment: Thanks, @Musa.  +1 I editted my post to include the initial and revised html for more clarity of rule 2 and rule 3.

Answer (score 1):

`.bluebutton a` and `a.bluebutton` are not equivalent. The first finds `a` elements that are **inside** an element with the class `bluebutton`. The second finds elements that are `a` elements **with** the class `bluebutton`.